# Nav buttons changing sizes on each page

Tags: html, css

this is the first ever website I am building from scratch and I am definitely jumping right in head first. I managed to get my index page complete and really like the buttons that I have for the navigation. The problem I am running into is the sizing. Everything on the index page is exactly how I want it, but when going to any other page the header becomes larger than what it is showing on the index and larger than what I want. I am new to scripting and still learning. Any help is appreciated!

I have tried messing with the sizes, margins, and padding of nav in .css but once things start going well on the pages I am trying to fix, it is affecting the index. I also tried messing with the formatting of the photo on the index page, but nothing I am doing seems to be doing the trick and searching for help is not getting me anywhere as I am not using query or react, etc.

I have thought about creating a separate div tag for these pages but that seems inefficient and uncommon in navigation tags!

Files > https://github.com/sumbernotas/Portfolio

```
<header>
            <h1 class="logo">SB</h1>
            <nav>
                <a href="./about.html">ABOUT</a>
                <a href="./projects.html">PROJECTS</a>
                <a href="./contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            </nav>
</header>
```

```
nav {
    text-align: right;
    width: 99%;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding-right: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1.7em;
  margin: 0 4.2em 0.1em 0;
  border: 0.16em solid rgb(46, 196, 182);
  border-radius: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: "Futara";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #7B7B7B;
  text-shadow: 0 0.04em 0.04em rgba(123, 123, 123);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

nav a:hover{
    color: #FDFFFC;
    background-color: #2EC4B6;
}
```

Comment: Some of your paddings and margins are in `em` units. Do you happen to have different font sizes across the pages?

Comment: I do have different sizes depending on the h1 and such. I used em because i was trying to get the button relative to the text that was in it (this could be the problem?) Ive never actually used em before this! I found on my pc at home, my problem described above is happening but I checked on a computer I have at work yesterdag and i am not having this issue, the nav looks the same on all pages but everything is much larger than it looks on my index page on my home pc @LawrenceWebDev